# Trying to use toggleclass with same classed divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use `Toggleclass` `js` function, if checkbox is checked adding active class to service classed `div`. But what I have tried, nothing can help me.

Can anyone give an idea about this ?

```
$(":checkbox").on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
});
```

I have tried this, but this function adding active to all divs which have services class. I need when I click on second label, it must add active class to services div.

And calc function is works for calculate checkbox values ;

```
var theTotal = parseFloat(0);
function calc(control) {
  if (control.checked == true) {
    theTotal += parseFloat(control.value);
  } else {
    theTotal-=parseFloat(control.value);
  }
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = theTotal;
}

<label><div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><div class="services active"><input onchange="calc(this)" class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="title1" id="1" value="0" disabled checked><label for="1"></label><span class="baslik">Title 1</span>  <span> <i class="fa fa-try" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>0 </span></div></div></label>
<label><div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><div class="services"><input onchange="calc(this)" class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="title2" id="2" value="20"><label for="2"></label><span class="baslik">Title 2</span>  <span> <i class="fa fa-try" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>20 </span> </div></div></label>
<label><div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><div class="services"><input onchange="calc(this)" class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="title3" id="3" value="20"><label for="3"></label><span class="baslik">Title 3</span>  <span> <i class="fa fa-try" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>20 </span> </div></div></label>
```

Comment: provide `calc()` function

Comment: @Emre Y. When you enter any community you should respect community basic principle. Stackoverflow community not encourage to do the entire job assigned by someone but help when you stuck anyhow. Why you trying working with JS if you don't have ABC knowledge about it? You should try something by yourself first.

Comment: @Hanif Like i said, I have tried everything about ToggleClass function but it doesnt works. When i click one class, it adds every active class to every div! I know ABC Knowledge.

Comment: Then where is your code?

Comment: I have updated my question @Hanif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just one function for both action

```js
function calc(control){
  var theTotal = parseFloat(0);  // set thetotal inside the function not outside
  var ParentElement = $(control.closest('.services')); // get the parent `services` element you can also use `.parent()` instead of .closest('.services')
  ParentElement.toggleClass('active');   // toggleClass active
  $('.magic-checkbox:checked').each(function(){  // loop through all the checked checkboxes to get the total
      theTotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
  });
  $("#total").html(theTotal);  // change the total html with the new total value
}
```

```css
.services.active{
  background : yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><div class="services active"><input onchange="calc(this)" class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="title1" id="1" value="0" disabled checked><label for="1"></label><span class="baslik">Title 1</span>  <span> <i class="fa fa-try" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>0 </span></div></div></label>
<label><div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><div class="services"><input onchange="calc(this)" class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="title2" id="2" value="20"><label for="2"></label><span class="baslik">Title 2</span>  <span> <i class="fa fa-try" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>20 </span> </div></div></label>
<label><div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><div class="services"><input onchange="calc(this)" class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="title3" id="3" value="20"><label for="3"></label><span class="baslik">Title 3</span>  <span> <i class="fa fa-try" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>20 </span> </div></div></label>


<div id="total"></div>
```

> **Note:** While I prefer to use jquery .. all this code in jquery .. you can find the deference

Comment: @EmreY. you're totally welcome .. check the `toggleClass` it will work too .. Have a great day and happy new year :-)

Comment: You have a great name as "Mohamed" and Im a php frontend developer, Trying to learn jquery, javascript too.

Thank you for being nice. Happy new year! :)

Comment: @EmreY. Thank You .. jquery is a very very simple way to work with js .. I recommend [This Videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNb8T5NBdQg&list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810) its 200 videos but each video is very short .. Don't waste your time learning pure javascript except if you need it .. I love Turkey BTW :-)  .. Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the class 'active' to all div with class 'services'

And add class to the current parent of clicked element.

Tell me if i'm right or not

:)

```js
$('.magic-checkbox').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('.services').toggleClass('active');
  getTotal();
})

function getTotal() {
  $(".total").html(function() {
      var total = 0;
      $(".active").each(function() {
          total += parseInt($(this).find('span:last').html());
      });
      return total;
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><div class="services active"><input class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="title1" id="1" value="0" disabled checked><label for="1"></label><span class="baslik">Title 1</span>  <span> <i class="fa fa-try" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>0 </span></div></div></label>
<label><div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><div class="services"><input class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="title2" id="2" value="20"><label for="2"></label><span class="baslik">Title 2</span>  <span> <i class="fa fa-try" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>20 </span> </div></div></label>
<label><div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><div class="services"><input class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="title3" id="3" value="20"><label for="3"></label><span class="baslik">Title 3</span>  <span> <i class="fa fa-try" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>20 </span> </div></div></label>

<br><span class="total">0</span>
```

Comment: It doesnt works like i want. Every label must work ownself

Comment: Yes! it works correct too. I have passed another step on my project thank you so much for your effort ! Have a nice day and happy new year

Comment: @EmreY. : Cool, happy new year to you too, good luck for your project ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a jquery code that will toggle class 'active' on the parent  when the checkbox is clicked.

HTML

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
 <div>
   <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" class="magic-checkbox" name="example" value="Bike"> Example Checkbox<br>
 </div>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".magic-checkbox").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: It doesnt adds any class to any element.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('.magic-checkbox').change(function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked')){
    $(this).closest('.services').addClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).closest('.services').removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><div class="services active"><input class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="title1" id="1" value="0" disabled checked><label for="1"></label><span class="baslik">Title 1</span>  <span> <i class="fa fa-try" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>0 </span></div></div></label>
<label><div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><div class="services"><input class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="title2" id="2" value="20"><label for="2"></label><span class="baslik">Title 2</span>  <span> <i class="fa fa-try" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>20 </span> </div></div></label>
<label><div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><div class="services"><input class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="title3" id="3" value="20"><label for="3"></label><span class="baslik">Title 3</span>  <span> <i class="fa fa-try" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>20 </span> </div></div></label>
```

Are you looking for this?